# Can I transform GPIO pins into a CAN bus

Tags: gpio

I need a CAN bus and the Raspberry Pi doesn't have this.

So, I would like to know if it is possible to transform some GPIO pins into a CAN bus.

Which libraries would permit this? I would like to program in Java, but I can program in C or C++ also.

Voltage will probably cause problems, but at this moment I just would like to know if it is possible to have the CAN protocol through the GPIO pins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly use GPIO to bit bang CAN signal due to timing issue, but you can use an interface chip like [MCP2515](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?dDocName=en010406) (SPI-to-CAN interface) to interface it from another bus. I did not found I2C-CAN interface, only SPI-CAN interface.

Answer (score 1):

There are CAN adaptors for the Pi on the market.  For example [this one](http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/pican-canbus-board-for-raspberry-pi-p-1196.html) from SK Pang.  According to the website it does require a custom kernel on the Pi.

I should point out that I have no connection with that company and haven't yet tried the adaptor.

If you are trying to connect the Pi to a car over Canbus, you may find it easier to use one of the many OBD adaptors.  Although the programmability is of course more restricted.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible in C, C++ or Java. The timing of the signals that make up the CAN protocol call for a dedicated CAN-controller or FPGA.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer.

If I understand well, i will not have good perfomances if I do this.
But for example i found this on the internet : http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/pican-canbus-board-for-raspberry-pi-p-1196.html

If I use a program using this board can I have good performance or not ?

In fact i really need an embedded computer with good performances (>= Raspberry Pi) with CAN output that i can program in Java or C++ or C (order of preferences).

Do you know any board that permit this (there are not a lot of arm board that have bus can inside....) ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about riscOS? I am sure it could work via SPI and a breakout board or something. No details though.